# How do I point my DreamHost DNS registered website to my EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, dreamhost

- I have a domain registered with Dreamhost
- I have an EC2 instance with the site running (that I can access by its IP address)
- I'm using Amazon Route 53 for a hosted zone
- I have pointed my DreamHost name servers to the ones provided by Amazon (and it has been over 48 hours)

The only thing I don't understand how to enter is the SOA record provided by Route 53.  There doesn't seem to be an option in the DreamHost DNS management console to add it.

Going to the website gives the standard "DNS record not found" from my service provider.

What am I missing?  I will really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Dreamhost:

- Use the values in NS (provided from AWS Route53) with your domain registrar(dreamhost).

In AWS Route53:

- Add an 'A Record' with IP of the EC2 instance in value.
- To resolve www to the naked domain name you could use, CNAME record, I have attached an image with some values masked.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: ahh, thank you.  Yes.  I didn't realize I was adding those records to route 53 and not dreamhost.